# How do I use Unix Domain sockets in zmq on Windows?

Tags: c++, zeromq

The following code works flawless on Linux but dies silently on Windows 10:

```cpp
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    // Prepare the context and the socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP); // REP stands for REPlies. This socket type is used to reply to incoming requests.

    try
    {
        socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/test.sock");
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error binding the socket: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Bound to socket. Waiting for the sender to connect and send a message..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion what I might do wrong?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: How far did it come, when stepping through line by line with the debugger? Maybe include the 1st two statements within the `try ... catch`.

Comment: @retired _"silently"_ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I'm asking for clarification. If no exception is generated then there's no reason for that code in the example. Since it is there I assume it serves a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The failure was a misconfigured CMakeFiles.txt which linked the zeromq lib dynamically (while I expected it to be linked statically) and the dll was not available at runtime.